# How to capture ListTile value to a TextField?

Tags: flutter

Hellow i have fetched data frome firestore to listTiles using listview,now i want to set the particular list tile value into the textField as i tap on it. this is what i have ringht now;

```
ListView.separated(
                                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                                  itemCount: snapshot.data!['Categories'] == null
                                                      ? 0
                                                      : snapshot
                                                          .data![
                                                              'Categories']
                                                          ?.length,
                                                  separatorBuilder:
                                                      (BuildContext context,
                                                              int index) =>
                                                          Divider(
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.grey,
                                                          ),
                                                  itemBuilder:
                                                      (BuildContext context,
                                                              int index) =>
                                                          Container(
                                                            child: Padding(
                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                                      .only(
                                                                  left: 20,
                                                                  right:
                                                                      20),
                                                              child:
                                                                  ListTile(
                                                                    
                                                                leading:
                                                                    CircleAvatar(
                                                                  radius:
                                                                      15,
                                                                  child: Text(
                                                                      '${index + 1}'),
                                                                ),
                                                                trailing: IconButton(
                                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                                      //DELETE CATEGORY
                                                                    },
                                                                    icon: Icon(
                                                                      Icons
                                                                          .delete_forever,
                                                                      color:
                                                                          Colors.red,
                                                                      size:
                                                                          30,
                                                                    )),
                                                                onTap: (){
                                                                  // set textfield value
                                                                  
                                                                },
                                                                title:
                                                                    Center(
                                                                  child:
                                                                      Text(
                                                                    snapshot.data!["Categories"][index]
                                                                        [
                                                                        "name"],
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color:
                                                                            Colors.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, Hope it will work for you. Thanks.

```
  class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {
      const ClassName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ClassNameState createState() => _ClassNameState();
    }
    
    class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> {
      final TextEditingController dataController = TextEditingController();
      String value = "";
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!['Categories'] == null
                  ? 0
                  : snapshot.data!['Categories']?.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          value = text;
                        },
                      ),
    
                      ///OR
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: dataController,
                        onChanged: (text){
                          controller.text = snapshot.data!["Categories"][index]["name"];
                        },
                      ),
                      
                      // child: ListTile(
                      //   leading: CircleAvatar(
                      //     radius: 15,
                      //     child: Text('${index + 1}'),
                      //   ),
                      //   trailing: IconButton(
                      //       onPressed: () {
                      //         //DELETE CATEGORY
                      //       },
                      //       icon: Icon(
                      //         Icons.delete_forever,
                      //         color: Colors.red,
                      //         size: 30,
                      //       )),
                      //   onTap: () {
                      //     // set textfield value
                      //   },
                      //   title: Center(
                      //     child: Text(
                      //       snapshot.data!["Categories"][index]["name"],
                      //       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      //     ),
                      //   ),
                      // ),
                    ),
                  )),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TextEditingController` to your `TextField` Or `TextFormField` like so

```dart
class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeWidgetState createState() => _SomeWidgetState();
}

class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  final TextEditingController textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  
  //..
}
```

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: textFieldController,
  //...
)
```

And when you tab on list item, run:

```dart
textFieldController.text = 'Your value'; // your list item's value
```